# How to subscribe to the drone's camera, using Mavsdk (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, mavlink

Im making android app, that have to get connection with drone, subscribe to the camera and display video with the any view. Couldnt find any useful documentation for java - just this thing: https://mavsdk.mavlink.io/v1.4/en/faq.html but there is nothing about java.

So, i made two layouts: first one, that gets address and port, second one that have to display the video. There is onCreate, that inits the server. init code looks like this:

```
MavsdkServer server = new MavsdkServer();
    private System drone;
    private Camera camera;
    public void initMavlink()
    {
        MavsdkEventQueue.executor().execute(() -> {
            server.run(SYSTEM_ADDRESS, MAVSDK_SERVER_PORT);
            drone = new System(SYSTEM_ADDRESS, MAVSDK_SERVER_PORT);
            camera = drone.getCamera();
        });



        Completable completable = camera.startVideoStreaming();



    }


    public void onTelemetryReceived(Telemetry telemetry) {
     

    }
```

Now i have no idea what to do, i cant find any method to subscribe streaming. Please, help me.

the dependencies i got:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'io.mavsdk:mavsdk:1.3.1'
    implementation 'io.mavsdk:mavsdk-server:1.3.1'
    implementation 'io.dronefleet.mavlink:mavlink:1.1.11'
    implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.4'
```